# Let's get critical: Jul 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Beer Stack Exchange](http://beer.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why cork a beer?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3391/why-cork-a-beer)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to chill a 30cl bottle to "cellar" temperature?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/how-to-chill-a-30cl-bottle-to-cellar-temperature)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a wide variation amongst specific styles?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/is-there-a-wide-variation-amongst-specific-styles)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there an example of the Trappist style that's considered the best of the style?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/is-there-an-example-of-the-trappist-style-thats-considered-the-best-of-the-styl)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is a good beer for starters, or people who don't typically enjoy the taste of beer?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/what-is-a-good-beer-for-starters-or-people-who-dont-typically-enjoy-the-taste)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does beer cause more fatigue than liquor?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/does-beer-cause-more-fatigue-than-liquor)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Where can you buy US craft beer in Europe that will ship to other EU countries?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/where-can-you-buy-us-craft-beer-in-europe-that-will-ship-to-other-eu-countries)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What other beer brands began as fictional but eventually became real?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/what-other-beer-brands-began-as-fictional-but-eventually-became-real)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Who made commercialization of beer possible](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/who-made-commercialization-of-beer-possible)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why does draught (draft) beer cause hangovers?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/why-does-draught-draft-beer-cause-hangovers)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---